# What's exactly the difference between ['#'] and [.='#']?

Tags: xpath

What's exactly the difference between `['#']` and `[.='#']`? Is there any difference at all?

In e.g. the following expressions:

```
<xsl:template match="a/@href[.='#']">...</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="a/@href['#']">...</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A predicate filters, if the contained expression is not true. `[.='#']` tests if the string content of the current context (`.`) equals `#`, thus the first template would return all `@href` attributes for links like `<a href="#">...</a>`.

The second template does not contain a boolean statement, and it also isn't numerical (so it would be a positional test). It will be evaluated as given by the [`boolean`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean) function:

> **Function**: `boolean boolean(object)`
>
> The boolean function converts its argument to a boolean as follows:
>
> - a number is true if and only if it is neither positive or negative
>     zero nor NaN
> - a node-set is true if and only if it is non-empty
> - a string is true if and only if its length is non-zero
> - an object of a type other than the four basic types is converted to a
>     boolean in a way that is dependent on that type

Here, we have a non-empty string with effective boolean value `true`, thus the predicate in your second template will never filter anything.

---

A predicate like in `//a[@href]` on the other hand would filter for all links containing an `@href` attribute (here, we filter for a node-set).

Comment: `thus the first query would return all @href attributes for links like` .. This is at least no true for XPath 1.0.. http://3v4l.org/39iRA

Comment: You omitted the `/@href` in the XPath expression. If you add it to resemble the query from the question, it will exactly do what I described in the answer.

Comment: @JensErat Thank you for the explanation and the hint to boolean evaluation. I just reread the specs and realized that I had forgotten that "A PredicateExpr is evaluated by evaluating the Expr and converting the result to a boolean".